# localScroll with a select menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, scrollto

I want to set up jQuery localScroll plugin to work with a select menu for smooth scrolling to the anchor links. This is my menu:

```
<select id="mobileMenu_top-nav" class="mobileMenu">
<option value="">Select a page</option>
<option value="http://www.conversionflow.nl/#open_image">Home</option>
<option value="http://www.conversionflow.nl/#page-content">Over ons</option>
<option value="http://www.conversionflow.nl/#features">Diensten</option>
<option value="http://www.conversionflow.nl/#testimonials">Testimonials</option>
<option value="http://www.conversionflow.nl/#contact-area">Contact</option>
<option value="http://www.conversionflow.nl/vacatures/">Vacatures</option>
<option value="http://www.conversionflow.nl/#featured-slider">Whitepaper</option>
</select>
```

And this is my script that works well with the other menu, but not with select menu:

```
jQuery( '#top-nav, #mobileMenu_top-nav' ).localScroll();
```

is it possible to make it somehow work with the select list?

Answer (score 0):

need to give the proper id in your script

use

`jQuery( '#mobileMenu_top-nav' ).localScroll();`

Comment: sorry that was my mistake... but still doesn't work with the proper id :-(